# Flask render_template and redirect not working after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, request

I have a page that sends data to the backend using a post ajax request when the user clicks a button, once the data is treated I want the user to be redirected to another page, but nothing happens:

```
@app.route('/validate', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def validate():
    tracks = observed_tracks(get_tracks())
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = (request.data.decode('UTF-8'))
        validated = json_parser(data)
        list_validated = validation(validated[1:])
        return render_template("tools/listvalidation.html",tracks=list_validated )
    return render_template("tools/validate.html", tracks=tracks)
```

I tried render_template, redirect, calling a function that calls render_template or redirect but nothing worked

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening on the result ? You need to find out why it is rendering the wrong template.

Comment: Literally nothing happens,
The functions:
        data = (request.data.decode('UTF-8'))
        validated = json_parser(data)
        list_validated = validation(validated[1:])
are correctly executed, but no line after the return render_template(...) gets executed, it's like if render_template didn't return anything.
It doesn't come from the template it's supposed to render, I can access it from the URL

Comment: But what is tracks saying? Or request method? You need to break it down to pieces and take it step by step, and then you will know what to do.

Comment: request.method says "POST"
tracks is a list of arrays I want to display in /listvalidation.html
I checked it, it's fine, even when i'm not passing an argument render_template doesn't do anything

Comment: Okay, but still, check what is "data" saying? what is "validated" saying? and so on

Comment: data contains a thousand-lines document about some music tracks.

validated turns the json into a list of arrays and compare them to the ones in the Database, and changes their attribute "validated" to True.

list_validated sends a list of arrays minus the header. I want these to be displayed in the next template to confirm what was done.
validated gives this kind of output:
['ArtisteLocal0298', 'AlbumN°9876', 'Titre01', 'Pop', '3:48', '(Lemeilleur)'], ['testgenreMenu', 'testgenreMenu', 'track01_testgenre', 'Folk', '02:00', 'shouldbefolk']]

 list_validated: 
[<Track 6>, <Track 15>]